# What software can I use to voice chat with my players while also being able to reproduce SFX comfortably?

Tags: audio, voip

I'm hosting an online Role Playing Game through Maptool and I need to be able to speak through the microphone while at the same time playing sounds from a soundboard without having to switch the capturing device (from microphone to stereo mix) every time I do this.

Comment: Please don't crosspost.

Comment: Not a cross-post,  my question was put on hold because it didn't fit the rpg SE and I was recommended to post it here instead

Comment: So, both the microphone input and the soundboard input would be merged into a single output? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes and no. Experimenting with both skype and teamspeak at the same time, it turns out my friends will get echo, because the stereo mix channel will reproduce their voices, and broadcast them at the same time. I thought "streaming" my stereo mix channel and having my friends receive SFX that way, but that means that if they spoke over VOIP they would hear themselves as well.

I really don't know how could I avoid having a stereo mix channel open and using VOIP at the same time while avoiding echo...

Comment: Are you (and your players) using headphones? If you are playing your players' audio to you out loud, they're gonna get feedback. If any of them play their audio out loud, you're gonna get feedback. Period.